# Someone else/another

Tags: idiomatic-language

*They fight a lot.*

1) *Then let's hope she finds someone else soon.*

2) *Then let's hope she finds another boyfriend soon.*

3) *Then let's hope she finds herself another boyfriend soon.*

In this example where she already has a boyfriend, which one of the sentences is more natural? Could I use them all?

Comment: If she already has a boyfriend, you could say : *"They fight a lot. Then let's hope she has already found someone else / another boyfriend."*